# Donde ver visualmente el icono de fontawesome para mi app en Angular

Tags: angularjs, importación, icons

Estoy trabajando en una app con Angular. Tengo fontawesome instalado según el articulo: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome.
Pude insertar los iconos de redes sociales gracias que en visual code cuando vas importando en el module.ts de angular te va da dando las opciones.

```
    import { faFacebook,faTwitter,faYoutube,faGithub,faLinkedin} from '@fortawesome/free- 
    brands-svg-icons';
```

Mi problema es que quiero visualizar el icono que quiero usar para luego importarlo y hacer uso de él. O sea, quiero entrar a https://fontawesome.com/ buscar mi icono y importarlo en el module.ts
Sucede que cuando me decido por uno, la pagina de fontawesome me lo da asi:

Y esto no me funciona ya que requiere otros pasos en el module.ts del componente.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

```
    @Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html'
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      faCoffee = faCoffee;
    }
```

para que finalmente se declare esto en el html.

```
    <fa-icon [icon]="faCoffee"></fa-icon>
```

En este caso quiero usar este "fa-right-to-bracket", trate de importarlo como faRightToBracket entre otras combinaciones y nada.
Me podrian dar una mano con esto? Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder usar el icono que quiere tienes que importarlo de la siguiente forma

```
import {faRightToBracket} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  faRightToBracket = faRightToBracket ;
}
```

Para que lo declares en el html

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faRightToBracket"/></fa-icon>
```

Comment: Gracias. Recien vi tu msg. Hace mucho de tu respuesta pero te debia un agradecimiento.